# Dynamically decoding response based on user-provided type

Tags: solidity, decoding

In Solidity, I want users to provide the [Solidity type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html) of a response upfront, and when the response arrives, I want to decode it based on the type that the user provided - basically dynamic decoding of sorts.

You can imagine something like:

```
abi.decode(responseData, (userProvidedType));
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately not.  You usually have to have a giant if/else handler.  You can also have different functions that take different types like hardhat's console (https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/main/packages/hardhat-core/console.sol). eg:

```
function a(uint) {}

function a(address){}
```